# Select specific column only if matches the ID in Eloquent

Tags: mysql, eloquent

I have an Eloquent query that looks like this:

```
return $contest->join('posts','contests.id','posts.contest_id')
                    ->join('winners', 'contests.winner_id', 'winners.id')
                    ->where('posts.user_id', $id)
                    ->where('winners.gold_user_id', $id)
                    ->orWhere('winners.silver_user_id', $id)
                    ->orWhere('winners.bronze_user_id', $id)
                    ->orderBy('contests.created_at', 'desc');
```

In SQL:

```
select * from `contests` 
    inner join `posts` on `contests`.`id` = `posts`.`contest_id` 
    inner join `winners` on `contests`.`winner_id` = `winners`.`id` 
    where `posts`.`user_id` = 4 
    and `winners`.`gold_user_id` = 4
    or `winners`.`silver_user_id` = 4 
    or `winners`.`bronze_user_id` = 4 
    order by `contests`.`created_at` desc
```

But my problem is, it displays all other contests entry that where the id is found.

This is my winner table :

[image]

What I want to do is to check if the user is a gold, silver or bronze winner. Now, with my query, it selects all columns where the id row matches. How can I attain my very goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `OR conditions` in parenthesis - like below

```
select * from `contests` 
    inner join `posts` on `contests`.`id` = `posts`.`contest_id` 
    inner join `winners` on `contests`.`winner_id` = `winners`.`id` 
    where `posts`.`user_id` = 4 
    and (`winners`.`gold_user_id` = 4
    or `winners`.`silver_user_id` = 4 
    or `winners`.`bronze_user_id` = 4)
    order by `contests`.`created_at` desc
```

**OP ELOQUENT QUERY**

```
return $contest->join('posts','contests.id','posts.contest_id')
                    ->join('winners', 'contests.winner_id', 'winners.id')
                    ->where('posts.user_id', $id)
                    ->where(function($query) use ($id) {
                        $query->where('winners.gold_user_id', $id)
                                ->orWhere('winners.silver_user_id', $id)
                                ->orWhere('winners.bronze_user_id', $id);
                    })
                    ->orderBy('contests.created_at', 'desc');
```